# Deploying phoenix framework on heroku with webpack

Tags: heroku, webpack, phoenix-framework

I followed the [docs](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/heroku) in the official website. The problem is I use webpack as my bundler instead of brunch. The deployment is successful. I can even access the api routes. My only problem is the assets (js,css) in the homepage is not found. Locally, I can access the home page successfully when I run `mix phoenix.server`.

I tried peeking at the `priv/static` folder in heroku (using `heroku run bash`) where the files are moved after being compiled and saw the asset files there. Did I miss anything? or a configuration that I should put?

Here is the remote deploy output
http://pastebin.com/1mL1YWTS

Here is my custom `compile` file *(to override phoenix-static buldpack)*
http://pastebin.com/BGHf9xBK

Here is my webpack.config.js
http://pastebin.com/Xv2E1yCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used webpack with the following `compile`:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack -p
mix phoenix.digest
```

You need to call `mix phoenix.digest` to generate a manifest that can be used in the static path helpers. http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phoenix.Digest.html#run/1

Comment: I thought `webpack -p` will tell that its in production. What's the digest for?

Comment: I check the environment variable and switch on production You should also be able to use `webpack -p`. Digest is used to compress static files. http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phoenix.Digest.html#run/1